# Console-only alternative for fslint?

Tags: server, package-management, filesystem, alternative

Are there any console-only alternatives to the `fslint` package in Ubuntu? I don't want to install `x11-common`, fonts and many of the other dependencies required by it on a server system.

Note: this is not just about finding duplicates. `fslint` offers all kinds of fine features to fix broken file/folder names, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) package is only a graphical wrapper for fslint bash scripts that can be found here:

http://fslint.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fslint/

There you will find the individual tools in quesition. See the [manpages for fslint](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fslint.1.html) for a description of the individual tools.

> **findup** - find DUPlicate files
>   **findnl** - find Name Lint (problems with filenames)
>   **findu8** - find filenames with invalid utf8 encoding
>   **findbl** - find Bad Links (various problems with symlinks)
>   **findsn** - find Same Name (problems with clashing names)
>   **finded** - find Empty Directories
>   **findid** - find files with dead user IDs
>   **findns** - find Non Stripped executables
>   **findrs** - find Redundant Whitespace in files
>   **findtf** - find Temporary Files
>   **findul** - find possibly Unused Libraries
>   **zipdir** - Reclaim wasted space in ext2 directory entries

Comment: Aaaaah, there we go. Thanks a bunch. That'd be the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I was aware of the individual tools, just not how to get them without getting the dependencies.

Comment: It looks better (for other people) if we had them listed.

Answer (score 4):

### fdupes

```
Searches  the  given  path for duplicate files. Such files are found by 
comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures,  followed  by  a  byte-by-byte
comparison.
```

To install

```
sudo apt-get install fdupes
```

[Here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fdupes.1.html) is the Ubuntu Manpage

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And +1 for the effort. It's not quite what I'm looking for it seems. The part of `fslint` I was interested in was about "invalid characters", file names in the same folder that can cause issues on a case-insensitive system etc ...

Comment: I believe there is also a CLI for `fslint`. Not tried it though.

Comment: any idea how I can then get rid of some of the dependencies of `fslint` that would only be needed if I wanted the GUI version anyway?

Comment: there's also the fork `jdupes` which tries to optimize `fdupes` for performance